# Defining an id for a script and referencing that id within the same script

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, I have a defined script with an ID so I may access it from the DOM. As you can see, I request the defined script in the DOM during the definition of the script. How does this not recursively call its self when requesting the innerhtml call?

My guess is that the DOM parses the defined script and placed the the ID into the DOM. During execution in the browser the JS gets the element by the ID and loads the HTML from the script. I feel like a recursive call would be constructed because during the execution on the browser side, we need to get the HTML in the innerHTML method, which will execute the JS script again?

Question: Is my assumption correct or am I missing something about the DOM, if so what is it that I do not know?

```html
<script id="myScript">
var x = 1;
var y = 2;

if (x != y) {
  var html_code = document.getElementById("myScript").innerHTML;
  //More JavaScript Below here
  console.log(html_code);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Run the code snippet. Do you see two (or rather an infinite number) `console.log`s? No? Then it's not executing the JS again.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption, that a request to `.innerHTML` will rerun the javascript is wrong. It will just return the text of the element.

Answer (score 1):

When you store the element's `innerHTML` into the variable `html_code`, the text that is inside the `<script>` tag -- that is, the actual script *itself* -- is returned, and it is displayed as text in the console. But just displaying that code won't actually execute it.

Now, if you were to use `eval()` on your `html_code` variable, *that* would execute the code. See the below example:

```html
<script id="myScript">
  var x = 1;
  var y = 2;

  if (x != y) {
    var html_code = document.getElementById("myScript2").innerHTML;
    //More JavaScript Below here
    eval(html_code);
  }
</script>

<script id="myScript2">
  alert("test");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That code returns the current **HTML** of an element.

Who executes the rendering/parsing/compiling process is the browser itself or whatever middleware who parses/renders/compiles the HTML code, scripts, Etc.

```html
<script id="myScript">
  var x = 1;
  var y = 2;

  if (x != y) {
    var html_code = document.getElementById("myScript").innerHTML;
    console.log(html_code)
  }
</script>
```

## Element.innerHTML

> The Element property `innerHTML` property is used to get or set a **string** representing serialized HTML describing the element's descendants.

So, that attribute won't execute any compiling process or script.